# Noun describing the act of controlling one's own mind

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

There's *mind control*, but it refers to controlling someone else's mind.

Is there a noun describing "mind control" or "thought control" in the sense of controlling one's own mind or thoughts?

Is *concentration* the closest it gets?

---

**Edit**: I'm looking chiefly for the mental, rather than the physical, aspect of "mind control", like abstaining from distractions, etc. This question may be somewhat hypothetical.

Comment: I'm not really sure how that would work -- mind control of others implies that you're able to use their minds to force them to do what you want. You can (should, at least) be able to "force" yourself to do what you want to do. Self-control, willpower, determination... Those might be related but I'm really not sure what kind of mind control you're talking about.

Comment: "calm", as a noun(a state of peace)

Comment: I think there are too many answers as it all depends on what particular religion/philosophy/behavioural therapy you espouse. Do you mean 'mind control' in the sense that you are able to stay true to your own thoughts and not be overcome by unwelcome ones? Some people are helped by their faith, others prefer secular therapies such as CBT/ACT/mindfulness. Or if you mean you are not easily distracted from the task in hand then you could be *focussed* (complimentary) or suffer from *tunnel vision* (not complimentary).

Comment: @EFrog Thanks, added an edit to define the intent of the question better.

Comment: Do you mean 'discipline'?

Comment: @Mynamite I mean the latter. Made an addition to reflect that. Thanks. Also, _focused_ and _tunnel vision_ seem quite useful for the question, you should probably add them as an answer.

Comment: "Mind control" is used in this sense also, especially in meditation terminology: http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/meditation

Comment: As a single word, I still think that "concentration" is the best word. It is also mentioned as "[attentional control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attentional_control)" which is the ability to concentrate. Bonus: [12 concentration exercises from 1918](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2012/08/08/12-concentration-exercises-from-1918/)

Comment: Mental discipline. Mathesis.

Comment: @AE Wow, those are actually really good. I'd suggest you add them as an answer.

Comment: The online definitions of "mathesis" that I see don't seem to match the desired meaning very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *mental discipline*
- *concentration*
- possibly also [*mathesis*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mathesis)

Answer (score 3):

There is a movement whose goal is to increase a person's self-awareness in order to attain tranquility and a mastery over self which is known as *mindfulness*.

Comment: +1 I like this "new-ish" term because it implies self-control but with a raised awareness in the process.

Answer (score 2):

A useful noun would be **focus**:

> 1640s, "point of convergence," from Latin focus "hearth, fireplace"   ...  taken by Kepler (1604) in a mathematical sense for "point of convergence,"   ...   (the purely optical sense of the word may
>   have existed before Kepler, but it is not recorded)   ...    **Sense transfer to "center of activity or energy" is first recorded 1796**. ([Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=focus))

If a person is *too* focussed, in a detrimental way, they could be said to have **tunnel vision**, which is used in a metaphorical way as well as being an actual medical condition.

1. (Pathology) a condition in which peripheral vision is greatly restricted
2. **narrowness of viewpoint resulting from concentration on a single idea, opinion, etc, to the exclusion of others** ([FreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tunnel+vision))

Answer (score 1):

> **SELF-POSSESSION** (*noun*): control of one's emotions or reactions especially when under stress; presence of mind, composure, self-control, self-possession, willpower, self-command, self-will; the trait of resolutely controlling your own behavior; confidence in one's own powers

From Definitions.net